# ring chart using pure css is pixel broken

Tags: html, css

I created a ring chart using the code below:

```html
<div class="chart-wrapper">
  <figure class="pie-chart" data-percentage="" style="--percentage:70%; --color:gray">
  </figure>
</div>
```

```css
.pie-chart {
  background:
    radial-gradient(
      circle closest-side,
      transparent 100%,
      white 0
    ),
    conic-gradient(
      var(--color) var(--percentage),
      rgba($color: green, $alpha: 100) 0,
      green 100%
  );
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  &:after {
    content:attr(data-percentage); 
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  line-height:normal;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);   
  }
}
```

But the result is not so smooth on Chrome(I try it first on Codepen). I think the problem could be coming from the gradient property but i'm not sure. Could somebody please help?:

[image]

Comment: sorry if I can't answer your question but I just want you to know that you can use free libraries for creating charts (including pie charts) like this one https://apexcharts.com/

Comment: I update the chart each second, is it performace suitable? Thx

Comment: yes of course, I've been using the libraries so many times in building a lot dashboards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `border-radius` instead of `radial-gradient`

```css
.pie-chart {
  background:conic-gradient(var(--color) var(--percentage), green 0);
  border-radius:50%;
  width: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.pie-chart:after {
  content: attr(data-percentage);
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: normal;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart-wrapper">
  <figure class="pie-chart" data-percentage="" style="--percentage:70%; --color:gray">
  </figure>
</div>
```